# Getting exception while deploying Mule app in test environment

Tags: xml, xsd, mule, xsd-validation

I am deploying my app in test environment and I am getting below exception -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning build 09-Jul-2018 08:30:36    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/schemadoc/3.9/mule-schemadoc.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
```

I am not able to understand why it is giving this error. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these errors come as the result of not having the correct dependency in your pom.xml (assuming you're running a Mavenized project), which can result from copying/pasting raw XML code, among other things.

Try removing the component you're trying to use from the palette, then re-add it. This should automatically add the dependency to your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks @jerney. I will do it.